# Create flow to send email notification when date = [Today]

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, email, notifications, flow

What is the best way to create a Microsoft Flow to send an email when date = [Today]? Used to be able to do this easily with SharePoint designer, I am now using SharePoint Online and it seems that Microsoft Flow is the best option.

The recommended templates don't seem to cover this situation well

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a timer job (recurrence) that runs once a day, check the condition (x day prior to due date) and then use exchage Send Email

(the extended version that I often use also checks a lot of other stuff like is the receiver blocked in the AD (not working here anymore) and so on)